# Computation of distance between multivariate continuous empirical measures

Tags: mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

Say we observe $X_1,...X_n$ (resp. $Y_1,...Y_n$) samples $\in \mathbb{R}^d$ drawn from a distribution $\mu$ (resp. $\nu$).

Let $\hat{\mu}_n$ (resp. $\hat{\nu}_n$) be the empirical measure based on the observations. **How can I assess the distance (in a certain sense) between $\hat{\mu}_n$ and $\hat{\nu}_n$ ?**

In the discrete case (samples belong to $\mathbb{Z}^d$), this is simple as we only need to look how many times a value $x$ has appeared in our samples $(X_i)_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n}$ and $(Y_i)_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n}$ $\forall x$ and then compute for instance $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x \in X} |\hat{\mu}_n(x) - \hat{\nu}_n(x)|$$ known as the *total variation distance.* This is an actual and easy to compute formula allowing me to compare multiple distributions and select the closest one to $\mu$ for example.

In the continuous case, The problem now being that almost surely $\hat{\mu}_n(x) \neq \hat{\nu}_n(x) ~\forall x$ :

**1- Does there exist a way to compute** $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\hat{\mu}_n(x) - \hat{\nu}_n(x)|dx$$

In the case of univariate continuous distributions, one can plot the histogram obtained from the samples, divide it into $M$ bins and compute $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{M} |\hat{\mu}_n(B_m) - \hat{\nu}_n(B_m)|$$

I am not sure about the way to extend this to the multivariate setting, plus  the fact that you have to select an accurate number of bins.

That being said, a various number of metrics also exist, namely Wasserstein distance, Hellinger distance and so on but I found none of them could solve this problem of multivariate continuous empirical measure distance computation.

**2- Can another metric solve this problem ? Am I missing something here ?**

Thank you.

Comment: Hellinger distance can be easily extended to multivariate problems, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52821/extending-the-hellinger-distance-to-multivariate-distributions, or am I missing something about this particular problem?

Comment: Well this would require to somehow estimate the density $f$ and $g$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ right ?